# How do I log in if I can not get the login prompt page to come up as it should?

Tags: 7

I am having some issues with my Drupal 7.

Because of a different bug I am having with component or panel, one that is taking over pages and hiding other parts of a page somehow, my login page has been corrupted.

what is supposed to be my /user and/or user/login page looks completely as it should not look. The username and password prompt and input fields are missing because of a component which needs to be removed. This component has somehow managed to cover or hide the thing I need.

The bug that has caused this problem is beyond the scope of this post but I believe that it is probably a requirement to log into the admin panel in order to fix the issue.

How do I log in if I can not get the login prompt page to come up as it should?

Answer (score 1):

> #### Drush
>
> To get one-time login for the specific user, use this syntax:
>
> ```
> drush uli <user>
> ```
>
> Where `<user>` is either uid (e.g. `1`), user name, or email address
>   for the user.
>
> #### Custom code
>
> You can use [`user_pass_reset_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_pass_reset_url/7.x) function in your
>   custom code.
>
> Generates a unique URL for a user to login and reset their password.
>
> Ex:
>
> ```
> $uid = 1;
> $account = user_load($uid);
> $link = user_pass_reset_url($account);
> ```

<sub>Source: Kenorb's answer to [How to get one time login for all the users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249607/how-to-get-one-time-login-for-all-the-users)</sub>

Comment: This is good and interesting.  What php file should I put this in and where?

Comment: Xarzu, do this in command line.

Comment: @xarzu you can put it in /modules/system/system.module inside of `function system_init() { ` add `print` on the link line. **[Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Siz.png)**.

Comment: @xarzu how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

From a browser window append

```
/?q=user
```

to the end of the url

If you've trashed the theme somehow, you might try resetting the theme to default garland with this https://www.drupal.org/node/200774

Comment: I have tried a number of things in this link but I have been unsuccessful.